# How to delete rows from googlespread sheet R

Tags: r, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dplyr

I have a dataframe, which I'm exporting to googlespread sheet using R with 'googlesheets' library.

```
DF

Col1         Col2        Col3 
ABC          DEF         Test
ABC          DEF         Pending
ABC          DEF         Final
ABC          DEF         Final
ABC          DEF         Reject
ABC          DEF         Test
```

I am using below mentioned code to export the datadataframe (Where `Col3` column is filled by user manually).

```
as<-gs_title("Test")
gs_upload("data.csv", sheet_title = "Test1", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Now, I want to remove only those rows, where `Col3` value is either `Final` or `Reject`.

Comment: @G5W: Yes, It was my bad

Comment: Are you looking for Apps Script to do this? Or are you trying to do this from R? Very different answers depending on your intent. I suggest you review the tags you've applied here and make sure that the proper ones are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function deleteSelectedRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][2].toString().toLowerCase()=="final" || vA[i][2].toString().toLowerCase()=="reject")  {
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+1)
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to schedule this on time basis, suppose I want this script to run automatically at 23:00 PM

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Comment: Ask another question and provide your current code with the new question

Comment: Sure and Thanks 